# Arithmetic operator overloading for a generic class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading, math, primitive-types

Given a generic class definition like

```
public class ConstrainedNumber<T> :
    IEquatable<ConstrainedNumber<T>>,
    IEquatable<T>,
    IComparable<ConstrainedNumber<T>>,
    IComparable<T>,
    IComparable where T:struct, IComparable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
```

How can I define arithmetic operators for it?

The following does not compile, because the '+' operator cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T':

```
public static T operator +( ConstrainedNumber<T> x, ConstrainedNumber<T> y)
{
    return x._value + y._value;
}
```

The generic type 'T' is constrained with the 'where' keyword as you can see, but I need a constraint for number types that have arithmetic operators (IArithmetic?).

'T' will be a primitive number type such as int, float, etc.  Is there a 'where' constraint for such types?

Comment: This is a huge drawback for C# as a language.  It seems generic arithmetic is a huge problem.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/1b7a80ea-34f3-428c-a469-9be1ec6e60ac
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/genericnumerics.aspx

It's not a problem in C++.

Comment: C# generics are not like C++ templates (which imho are a kind of compiler macro's). C# generics are resolved at runtime, c++ templates at compile time, wich is why a c++ compiler can resolve this operators (it can verify at compile time that the template type implements the operator), and c# can't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74796391/199364: *C# 11 / .NET 7 gives us this: "... where T : INumber<T>" ...*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the best you'd be able to do is use `IConvertible` as a constraint and do something like:

```
 public static operator T +(T x, T y)
    where T: IConvertible
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if (type == typeof(String) ||
        type == typeof(DateTime)) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The type {0} is not supported", type.FullName), "T");

    try { return (T)(Object)(x.ToDouble(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo) + y.ToDouble(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)); }
    catch(Exception ex) { throw new ApplicationException("The operation failed.", ex); }
}
```

That won't stop someone from passing in a String or DateTime though, so you might want to do some manual checking - but IConvertible should get you close enough, and allow you to do the operation.

Comment: I actually changed it to a Double, since it is the largest numeric type with the most precision, and then it gets boxed back to whatever T is. This should work, but I make no guarantees about it's performance :D

Comment: Yeah but then you'd have to do it specifically for each type. This is a bit hacky, true, but it should give you coverage for everything.

Comment: Argh stop deleting your comments :D

Comment: Ok! +Involves writing no new code. +Primitive number types all use IConvertible. +Subclasses always specify 'T' as a primative numeric, so no error risk.  +The where constraint involves no cast to interface, so 'ToDouble' is fast as non-generic, and ToDouble implementation generally returns 'this'.

Comment: Sorry about the comment rush.  I was analyzing the pros/cons of this answer.  If subclasses using ConstrainNumber<T> always specify T as a numeric, the type-checking and error handling is unnecessary, which is a huge plus.  Only downside I see is the required highest-precision arithmetic and boxing.

Comment: np :) generics make my head spin sometimes too!

Comment: I could actually avoid the boxing by just having the operator return the double, since arithmetic expressions using the operator can handle casting (without boxing) as necessary. I don't have to convert back to ConstrainedNumber<T> until the point of assignment anyway, where the constraining matters

Comment: Performance-wise, I'm not worried about ToDouble.  It just call the static, type-specific overload of Convert.ToDouble(int x), which just returns x, since it's an implicit conversion!  Since we constrained T with 'where' as IConvertible, it's a compile-time check, so ToDouble is a standard call.

Comment: NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo can be null instead, since ToDouble ignores the parameter (according to Reflector) for the primitive types.
Final code:

public static double operator +( ConstrainedNumber<T> x, ConstrainedNumber<T> y) {return x._value.ToDouble(null) + y._value.ToDouble(null);}

Comment: I'm sorry, but does that even compile `public static operator T +(T x, T y) where T: IConvertible`? T is supposed to be a generic argument of the class and at least one of the 2 arguments must be of the type of the enclosing class which is not `T` but `ConstrainedNumber<T>`. If you managed to make a generic operator overload of a non generic class I would be more than interested to hear.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately there is no way to constrain a  generic parameter to be an integral type (**Edit:** I guess "arithmetical type" might be a better word as this does not pertain to just integers).

It would be nice to be able to do something like this:

```
where T : integral // or "arithmetical" depending on how pedantic you are
```

or

```
where T : IArithmetic
```

I would suggest that you read [Generic Operators](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/genericoperators.html) by our very own Marc Gravell and Jon Skeet.  It explains why this is such a difficult problem and what can be done to work around it.

> .NET 2.0 introduced generics into the
> .NET world, which opened the door for
> many elegant solutions to existing
> problems. Generic constraints can be
> used to restrict the type-arguments to
> known interfaces etc, to ensure access
> to functionality - or for simple
> equality/inequality tests the
> Comparer.Default and
> EqualityComparer.Default
> singletons implement IComparer and
> IEqualityComparer  respectively
> (allowing us to sort elements for
> instance, without having to know
> anything about the "T" in question).
>
> With all this, though, there is still
> a big gap when it comes to operators.
> Because operators are declared as
> static methods, there is no IMath
> or similar equivalent interface that
> all the numeric types implement; and
> indeed, the flexibility of operators
> would make this very hard to do in a
> meaningful way. Worse: **many of the
> operators on primitive types don't
> even exist as operators; instead there
> are direct IL methods.** [emphasis mine] To make the
> situation even more complex,
> Nullable<> demands the concept of
> "lifted operators", where the inner
> "T" describes the operators applicable
> to the nullable type - but this is
> implemented as a language feature, and
> is not provided by the runtime (making
> reflection even more fun).

Comment: That article was almost entirely written by Marc Gravell, in fact - who also wrote the helper classes in MiscUtil.

Comment: "...there is no IMath or similar equivalent interface that all the numeric types implement."  Actually, all the numeric types implement IConvertible, which for all numeric types (byte,sbyte,short,ushort,int,uint,long,ulong,float,double,decimal) results in a simple implicit or explicit conversion at compile-time through a call to IConvertible.ToDecimal (internally Convert.ToDecimal) in my arithmetic overloads.  The decimal type is precise enough to store all the other types, including Int64 (~20 significant figures).  This is perfect on platforms that support decimal arithmetic in the hardware.

Comment: Such an interface exists now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74796391/14637

Answer (score 13):

In C# 4.0 you can use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) to get round this limitation. I had a look at your code, and managed to produce a working (albeit cutdown) version:

```
 public class ConstrainedNumber<T> where T : struct, IComparable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
    {
        private T _value;

        public ConstrainedNumber(T value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public static T operator +(ConstrainedNumber<T> x, ConstrainedNumber<T> y)
        {
            return (dynamic)x._value + y._value;
        }
    }
```

And a little test program to go with it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConstrainedNumber<int> one = new ConstrainedNumber<int>(10);
        ConstrainedNumber<int> two = new ConstrainedNumber<int>(5);
        var three = one + two;
        Debug.Assert(three == 15);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: A note to future readers, casting a value type to `dynamic` causes a boxing allocation and if your code is performance critical this might (will?) have an impact.

Answer (score 7):

C# 11 / .NET 7 gives us this:

```cs
public class ConstrainedNumber<T> where T : INumber<T>
{
    T _value;
    public static T operator +(ConstrainedNumber<T> x, ConstrainedNumber<T> y)
    {
        return x._value + y._value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, this does not work. But there are some suggestions on how to solve the problem. I did the following (using some ideas from different sources on the net):

```
public delegate TResult BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult>(TLeft left, TRight right);

/// <summary>
/// Provide efficient generic access to either native or static operators for the given type combination.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TLeft">The type of the left operand.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TRight">The type of the right operand.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the result value.</typeparam>
/// <remarks>Inspired by Keith Farmer's code on CodeProject:<br/>http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/genericoperators.aspx</remarks>
public static class Operator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> {
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> addition;
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> bitwiseAnd;
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> bitwiseOr;
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> division;
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> exclusiveOr;
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> leftShift;
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> modulus;
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> multiply;
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> rightShift;
    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> subtraction;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the addition operator + (either native or "op_Addition").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The addition operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> Addition {
        get {
            if (addition == null) {
                addition = CreateOperator("op_Addition", OpCodes.Add);
            }
            return addition;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the modulus operator % (either native or "op_Modulus").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The modulus operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> Modulus {
        get {
            if (modulus == null) {
                modulus = CreateOperator("op_Modulus", OpCodes.Rem);
            }
            return modulus;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the exclusive or operator ^ (either native or "op_ExclusiveOr").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The exclusive or operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> ExclusiveOr {
        get {
            if (exclusiveOr == null) {
                exclusiveOr = CreateOperator("op_ExclusiveOr", OpCodes.Xor);
            }
            return exclusiveOr;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the bitwise and operator &amp; (either native or "op_BitwiseAnd").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The bitwise and operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> BitwiseAnd {
        get {
            if (bitwiseAnd == null) {
                bitwiseAnd = CreateOperator("op_BitwiseAnd", OpCodes.And);
            }
            return bitwiseAnd;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the division operator / (either native or "op_Division").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The division operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> Division {
        get {
            if (division == null) {
                division = CreateOperator("op_Division", OpCodes.Div);
            }
            return division;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the multiplication operator * (either native or "op_Multiply").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The multiplication operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> Multiply {
        get {
            if (multiply == null) {
                multiply = CreateOperator("op_Multiply", OpCodes.Mul);
            }
            return multiply;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the bitwise or operator | (either native or "op_BitwiseOr").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The bitwise or operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> BitwiseOr {
        get {
            if (bitwiseOr == null) {
                bitwiseOr = CreateOperator("op_BitwiseOr", OpCodes.Or);
            }
            return bitwiseOr;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the left shift operator &lt;&lt; (either native or "op_LeftShift").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The left shift operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> LeftShift {
        get {
            if (leftShift == null) {
                leftShift = CreateOperator("op_LeftShift", OpCodes.Shl);
            }
            return leftShift;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the right shift operator &gt;&gt; (either native or "op_RightShift").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The right shift operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> RightShift {
        get {
            if (rightShift == null) {
                rightShift = CreateOperator("op_RightShift", OpCodes.Shr);
            }
            return rightShift;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the subtraction operator - (either native or "op_Addition").
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The subtraction operator.</value>
    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> Subtraction {
        get {
            if (subtraction == null) {
                subtraction = CreateOperator("op_Subtraction", OpCodes.Sub);
            }
            return subtraction;
        }
    }

    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> CreateOperator(string operatorName, OpCode opCode) {
        if (operatorName == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("operatorName");
        }
        bool isPrimitive = true;
        bool isLeftNullable;
        bool isRightNullable = false;
        Type leftType = typeof(TLeft);
        Type rightType = typeof(TRight);
        MethodInfo operatorMethod = LookupOperatorMethod(ref leftType, operatorName, ref isPrimitive, out isLeftNullable) ??
                                    LookupOperatorMethod(ref rightType, operatorName, ref isPrimitive, out isRightNullable);
        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", operatorName, typeof(TLeft).FullName, typeof(TRight).FullName, typeof(TResult).FullName), typeof(TResult),
                                                 new Type[] {typeof(TLeft), typeof(TRight)});
        Debug.WriteLine(method.Name, "Generating operator method");
        ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();
        if (isPrimitive) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Primitives using opcode", "Emitting operator code");
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            if (isLeftNullable) {
                generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(TLeft).GetMethod("op_Explicit", BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static), null);
            }
            IlTypeHelper.ILType stackType = IlTypeHelper.EmitWidening(generator, IlTypeHelper.GetILType(leftType), IlTypeHelper.GetILType(rightType));
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            if (isRightNullable) {
                generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(TRight).GetMethod("op_Explicit", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static), null);
            }
            stackType = IlTypeHelper.EmitWidening(generator, IlTypeHelper.GetILType(rightType), stackType);
            generator.Emit(opCode);
            if (typeof(TResult) == typeof(object)) {
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Box, IlTypeHelper.GetPrimitiveType(stackType));
            } else {
                Type resultType = typeof(TResult);
                if (IsNullable(ref resultType)) {
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(TResult).GetConstructor(new Type[] {resultType}));
                } else {
                    IlTypeHelper.EmitExplicit(generator, stackType, IlTypeHelper.GetILType(resultType));
                }
            }
        } else if (operatorMethod != null) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Call to static operator method", "Emitting operator code");
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, operatorMethod, null);
            if (typeof(TResult).IsPrimitive && operatorMethod.ReturnType.IsPrimitive) {
                IlTypeHelper.EmitExplicit(generator, IlTypeHelper.GetILType(operatorMethod.ReturnType), IlTypeHelper.GetILType(typeof(TResult)));
            } else if (!typeof(TResult).IsAssignableFrom(operatorMethod.ReturnType)) {
                Debug.WriteLine("Conversion to return type", "Emitting operator code");
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(TResult));
                generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle", new Type[] {typeof(RuntimeTypeHandle)}), null);
                generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ChangeType", new Type[] {typeof(object), typeof(Type)}), null);
            }
        } else {
            Debug.WriteLine("Throw NotSupportedException", "Emitting operator code");
            generator.ThrowException(typeof(NotSupportedException));
        }
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult>));
    }

    private static bool IsNullable(ref Type type) {
        if (type.IsGenericType && (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))) {
            type = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static MethodInfo LookupOperatorMethod(ref Type type, string operatorName, ref bool isPrimitive, out bool isNullable) {
        isNullable = IsNullable(ref type);
        if (!type.IsPrimitive) {
            isPrimitive = false;
            foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public)) {
                if (methodInfo.Name == operatorName) {
                    bool isMatch = true;
                    foreach (ParameterInfo parameterInfo in methodInfo.GetParameters()) {
                        switch (parameterInfo.Position) {
                        case 0:
                            if (parameterInfo.ParameterType != typeof(TLeft)) {
                                isMatch = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (parameterInfo.ParameterType != typeof(TRight)) {
                                isMatch = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            isMatch = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isMatch) {
                        if (typeof(TResult).IsAssignableFrom(methodInfo.ReturnType) || typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(methodInfo.ReturnType)) {
                            return methodInfo; // full signature match
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

internal static class IlTypeHelper {
    [Flags]
    public enum ILType {
        None = 0,
        Unsigned = 1,
        B8 = 2,
        B16 = 4,
        B32 = 8,
        B64 = 16,
        Real = 32,
        I1 = B8, // 2
        U1 = B8|Unsigned, // 3
        I2 = B16, // 4
        U2 = B16|Unsigned, // 5
        I4 = B32, // 8
        U4 = B32|Unsigned, // 9
        I8 = B64, //16
        U8 = B64|Unsigned, //17
        R4 = B32|Real, //40
        R8 = B64|Real //48
    }

    public static ILType GetILType(Type type) {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        }
        if (!type.IsPrimitive) {
            throw new ArgumentException("IL native operations requires primitive types", "type");
        }
        if (type == typeof(double)) {
            return ILType.R8;
        }
        if (type == typeof(float)) {
            return ILType.R4;
        }
        if (type == typeof(ulong)) {
            return ILType.U8;
        }
        if (type == typeof(long)) {
            return ILType.I8;
        }
        if (type == typeof(uint)) {
            return ILType.U4;
        }
        if (type == typeof(int)) {
            return ILType.I4;
        }
        if (type == typeof(short)) {
            return ILType.U2;
        }
        if (type == typeof(ushort)) {
            return ILType.I2;
        }
        if (type == typeof(byte)) {
            return ILType.U1;
        }
        if (type == typeof(sbyte)) {
            return ILType.I1;
        }
        return ILType.None;
    }

    public static Type GetPrimitiveType(ILType iLType) {
        switch (iLType) {
        case ILType.R8:
            return typeof(double);
        case ILType.R4:
            return typeof(float);
        case ILType.U8:
            return typeof(ulong);
        case ILType.I8:
            return typeof(long);
        case ILType.U4:
            return typeof(uint);
        case ILType.I4:
            return typeof(int);
        case ILType.U2:
            return typeof(short);
        case ILType.I2:
            return typeof(ushort);
        case ILType.U1:
            return typeof(byte);
        case ILType.I1:
            return typeof(sbyte);
        }
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("iLType");
    }

    public static ILType EmitWidening(ILGenerator generator, ILType onStackIL, ILType otherIL) {
        if (generator == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("generator");
        }
        if (onStackIL == ILType.None) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Stack needs a value", "onStackIL");
        }
        if (onStackIL < ILType.I8) {
            onStackIL = ILType.I8;
        }
        if ((onStackIL < otherIL) && (onStackIL != ILType.R4)) {
            switch (otherIL) {
            case ILType.R4:
            case ILType.R8:
                if ((onStackIL&ILType.Unsigned) == ILType.Unsigned) {
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_R_Un);
                } else if (onStackIL != ILType.R4) {
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_R8);
                } else {
                    return ILType.R4;
                }
                return ILType.R8;
            case ILType.U8:
            case ILType.I8:
                if ((onStackIL&ILType.Unsigned) == ILType.Unsigned) {
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_U8);
                    return ILType.U8;
                }
                if (onStackIL != ILType.I8) {
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8);
                }
                return ILType.I8;
            }
        }
        return onStackIL;
    }

    public static void EmitExplicit(ILGenerator generator, ILType onStackIL, ILType otherIL) {
        if (otherIL != onStackIL) {
            switch (otherIL) {
            case ILType.I1:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I1);
                break;
            case ILType.I2:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I2);
                break;
            case ILType.I4:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I4);
                break;
            case ILType.I8:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8);
                break;
            case ILType.U1:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_U1);
                break;
            case ILType.U2:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_U2);
                break;
            case ILType.U4:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_U4);
                break;
            case ILType.U8:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_U8);
                break;
            case ILType.R4:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_R4);
                break;
            case ILType.R8:
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_R8);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use like this:
    int i = Operator.Addition(3, 5);

Comment: An interesting approach, but it looks like it belongs in a C# compiler, rather than a C# program.  It looks like this is an automated version of manually building an IArithmetic<T> class, and implementations of it such as IntArithmetic:IArithmetic<int>, etc., which would provide compile-time checks.

Comment: I've regretted several times so far that generic type constraints were not more flexible. Two things: specifying method signatures, for instance through implicit interface mapping, would be great (but I understand the technical challenges of this). Second, more BCL interfaces for the primitives etc.

Comment: (comments are too short ;) )
Indeed, this is an approach to overcome some of these limitations. But they will obviously not be able to produce compile-time checking, except maybe if combined with a toolset such as PostSharp to directly inject "good" code and complain about invalid combinations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using to much types which are used as generic argument and want to have compile-time checks, then you can use a solution which is similar to Lucero's solution.

#### Base class

```
public class Arithmetic<T>
{
    protected static readonly Func<T, T, T> OP_ADD;
    protected static readonly Func<T, T, T> OP_MUL;
    protected static readonly Func<T, T, T> OP_SUB;
    /* Define all operators you need here */

    static Arithmetic()
    {
        Arithmetic<Single>.OP_ADD = (x, y) => x + y;
        Arithmetic<Single>.OP_MUL = (x, y) => x * y;
        Arithmetic<Single>.OP_SUB = (x, y) => x - y;

        Arithmetic<Double>.OP_ADD = (x, y) => x + y;
        Arithmetic<Double>.OP_MUL = (x, y) => x * y;
        Arithmetic<Double>.OP_SUB = (x, y) => x - y;

        /* This could also be generated by a tool */
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
public class Vector2<T> : Arithmetic<T>
{
    public T X;
    public T Y;

    public static Vector2<T> operator +(Vector2<T> a, Vector2<T> b)
    {
        return new Vector2<T>()
        {
            X = OP_ADD(a.X, b.X),
            Y = OP_ADD(a.Y, b.Y)
        };
    }
    public static Vector2<T> operator -(Vector2<T> a, Vector2<T> b)
    {
        return new Vector2<T>()
        {
            X = OP_SUB(a.X, b.X),
            Y = OP_SUB(a.Y, b.Y)
        };
    }
    public static Vector2<T> operator *(Vector2<T> a, Vector2<T> b)
    {
        return new Vector2<T>()
        {
            X = OP_MUL(a.X, b.X),
            Y = OP_MUL(a.Y, b.Y)
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There aren't constraints available for that but there is a way to get around the problem:

```
public static T operator -(T foo, T bar)
{
    return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(
            System.Convert.ToDecimal(foo)
                -
            System.Convert.ToDecimal(bar),
                typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: There are constraints available now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74796391/14637

Answer (score 1):

I just did this after looking here. The Vector4<T> class contains 4 numbers/axis of type T with the usual vector math. Just add 2 implicit ops to convert to and from Decimal. This is probably as un-verbose as you're going to get, but as you point out, more precise and thus heavier than it needs to be. Like you guys, I wish there was an INumeric or something!

```
public static Vector4<T> operator +(Vector4<T> a, Vector4<T> b)
{
    Vector4<Decimal> A = a;
    Vector4<Decimal> B = b;

    var result = new Vector4<Decimal>(A.X + B.X, A.Y + B.Y, A.Z + B.Z, A.W + B.W);

    return result;
}

public static implicit operator Vector4<Decimal>(Vector4<T> v)
{
    return new Vector4<Decimal>(
        Convert.ToDecimal(v.X), 
        Convert.ToDecimal(v.Y), 
        Convert.ToDecimal(v.Z), 
        Convert.ToDecimal(v.W));
}

public static implicit operator Vector4<T>(Vector4<Decimal> v)
{
    return new Vector4<T>(
        (T)Convert.ChangeType(v.X, typeof(T)), 
        (T)Convert.ChangeType(v.Y, typeof(T)), 
        (T)Convert.ChangeType(v.Z, typeof(T)), 
        (T)Convert.ChangeType(v.W, typeof(T)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this friends (using the RTTI and the object class)

```
class MyMath
{
    public static T Add<T>(T a, T b) where T: struct
    {
        switch (typeof(T).Name)
        {
            case "Int32":
                return (T) (object)((int)(object)a + (int)(object)b);
            case "Double":
                return (T)(object)((double)(object)a + (double)(object)b);
            default:
                return default(T);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyMath.Add<double>(3.6, 2.12));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be called 'casting gore'

Answer (score 0):

There is no current support in .Net generics to indicate that operators are supported.

This is an oft requested feature.

It can be semi worked around (see  [MiscUtils](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html)) but this will not give you the syntax you desire

Comment: This answer is no longer true, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74796391/14637

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some potential solutions involving expression trees, where the operator expression is created manually.

It's not perfect because you lose compile-time verification, but it might do the trick for you.

[here's](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html) an article about that.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do something like this I'd probably approach it along the lines of

```
public class ConstrainedNumber<T>
{
    private T Value { get; }
    public ConstrainedNumber(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    private static Func<ConstrainedNumber<T>, ConstrainedNumber<T>, T> _addFunc; // Cache the delegate
    public static ConstrainedNumber<T> operator+(ConstrainedNumber<T> left, ConstrainedNumber<T> right)
    {
        var adder = _addFunc;
        if (adder == null)
        {
            ParameterExpression lhs = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ConstrainedNumber<T>));
            ParameterExpression rhs = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ConstrainedNumber<T>));
            _addFunc = adder = Expression.Lambda<Func<ConstrainedNumber<T>, ConstrainedNumber<T>, T>>(
                Expression.Add(
                    Expression.Property(lhs, nameof(Value)),
                    Expression.Property(lhs, nameof(Value))
                    ),
                lhs,
                rhs).Compile();
        }
        return new ConstrainedNumber<T>(adder(left, right));
    }
}
```

The end result is a bit like the end result of the `dynamic` approach, which will in fact end up internally doing something like this but with a bit more overhead, and should work for any `T` that is either an arithmetic primitive or has a `+` operator defined for it. The one case that the `dynamic` approach would handle differently is that it would work for `string` while this wouldn't. Whether that's a good or bad thing depends on the use case but if it was needed `string` could be special-cased.