# Defining Typed Parameters as the Ones that Define Operator Overloading

Tags: c#, generics

Is there anyway to define type parameter `T` as the ones that define operator overloading? Take for example, I need to create a generic `Add` function with the parameter `T`. Obviously, the T must defined the `+` operator, i.e.,

```
 public static T operator +(T c1,T c2)
 {
// plus operation
 }
```

Is there anyway to constraint `T` so that it is restricted to the types that overload the operators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Keeping it short as this question has been duplicated many times.

e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756954/arithmetic-operator-overloading-for-a-generic-class-in-c)