# Sum on User Defined Types C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to do Sum operation on a custom defined type class Percentage

```
public class Percentage
{
    private readonly decimal pctDecimal; //This has to be private

    public Percentage(decimal decimal_value)
    {
        this.pctDecimal = decimal_value;
    }
}
```

I am using an Extension method to do the sum

```
public static class SumExtensions
{
    public static Percentage Sum(this IEnumerable<Percentage> source)
    {
        return source.Aggregate((x, y) =>
        {
            (x + y); //I am getting Error here that "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of Type Percentage and Percentage."
        });
    }

}
```

[image]

Any Solution here?

Comment: Overload the `+` operator???

Comment: `source.Aggregate((x, y) => (x + y))` no braces

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Overload generic + operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307915/c-sharp-overload-generic-operator)

Comment: @Charlieface that actually works. Thanks

Comment: You do realize that summing percentages doesn't really mathematical sense...30/50 -- 60% + 80/100 --> 80% == 110/150 --> 73.3% not 140%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overload `+` operator. For example:

```cs
public class Percentage
{
    private readonly decimal pctDecimal; //This has to be private

    public Percentage(decimal decimal_value)
    {
        this.pctDecimal = decimal_value;
    }

    public static Percentage operator +(Percentage a, Percentage b)
        => new Percentage(a.pctDecimal + b.pctDecimal);
}
```

Comment: is this only going to work on 2 Percentage Objects? any way to extend it to a list of objects?

Comment: It works for two objects - `+` is a binary operation. However, now, you can use your `SumExtensions`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your decimal propery

```
public class Percentage
{
    private readonly decimal pctDecimal;
    public decimal PctDecimal { get {return pctDecimal;} }

    public Percentage(decimal decimal_value)
    {
        this.pctDecimal = decimal_value;
    }
}


public static class SumExtensions
{
    public static Percentage Sum(this IEnumerable<Percentage> source)
    {
        return source.Aggregate((x, y) =>
        {
            (x.PctDecimal  + y.PctDecimal );
        });
    }
}
```