# .NET interface/constraint for object that implements certain operators

Tags: c#, .net, generics, operators, operator-overloading

I was making a generic method and was wondering if there is some way of adding a constraint to a generic type `T`, such that `T` has a certain operator, like +, +=, -, -=, etc.

```
public void TestAdd<T>(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1 + t2;
}
```

Produces the following error text:

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

I searched around on Google/SO for a while and couldn't really find anything related.

Comment: See: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756954/arithmetic-operator-overloading-for-a-generic-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solution for overloaded operator constraint in .NET generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics)

Comment: Thanks lazyberezovsky, that answers it. Unfortunately it's not supported. Not going near his dynamic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this cannot be done

You can do it less fancy by :

```
interface IAddable { void Add(object item); }
...
public void TestAdd<T>(T t1, T t2) where T : IAddable
{
   return t1.Add(t2);
}
```

Comment: My guess is he is trying to support built-in types such as int, double, decimal, etc. None of those would implement your custom interface.

Comment: Yea, was trying to avoid a custom interface and see if there was native support for constraining based on the operators of the object.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm afraid this is not supported, this was the closest alternative I could think of