# How can I use a generic type parameter with an operator overload?

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading, generic-type-argument

I want to overload an operator in a class. I want the overload method to be generic. For example:

```
class Subtractable
{
    public static Subtractable operator-<T>(Subtractable a, T b)
    {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

When I do this, I get the following message at the generic type parameter:

> Syntax error, '(' expected

If I remove the generic type parameter, I get the following message at `b`'s type:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there some way to achieve this? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: See this old post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756954/arithmetic-operator-overloading-for-a-generic-class-in-c-sharp