# how to overload an operator of a generic class with operands of different generic types of the generic class

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

There have been a lot of similar questions asked but all involve operands of same type or same generic type. This one in particular ([How can I use a generic type parameter with an operator overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381285/how-can-i-use-a-generic-type-parameter-with-an-operator-overload)) is close to what I am looking for but no answer or work-around.

Is it possible to do something like this for the ‘*’ operator overload:

```
public class MyNumericClass<T>
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    //OK but works only for same type operands
    public static double operator *(MyNumericClass<T> left, MyNumericClass<T> right)
    {
        return left.Value * right.Value;
    }

    //****Pseudo Code for different type operands - not OK****
    public static double operator *<TRight>(MyNumericClass<T> left, MyNumericClass<TRight> right)
    {
        return left.Value * right.Value;
    }

    static void Test()
    {
        MyNumericClass<int> i = new MyNumericClass<int>();
        MyNumericClass<int> j = new MyNumericClass<int>();
        MyNumericClass<string> s = new MyNumericClass<string>();
        double r1 = i * j;
        double r2 = i * s; //Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands...
    }
}
```

I need to have a specific overload for different generic types. A non-generic superclass will not do in this case as I have other overloads of the operator (not shown here) and ambiguous calls will be produced if I use a parameter of superclass type and not the exact generic type.

Is it possible to do this or is there a work-around? Is it possible to use op_Multiply instead? (Tried it but couldn’t make it work).

P.S. I don’t see any reason why something like this should not be possible.

**EDIT1**
After people's answers and comments I am adding another version of the class with the implicit casts and more overloads to demonstrate the call ambiguity and why the answers provided do not solve my problem. I need to specify the different generic type in my operator overload to resolve this:

```
public class MyNumericClass<T>
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator double(MyNumericClass<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyNumericClass<T>(double value)
    {
        MyNumericClass<T> c = new MyNumericClass<T>();
        c.Value = value;
        return c;
    }

    public static MyNumericClass<T> operator *(double left, MyNumericClass<T> right)
    {
        return left * right.Value;
    }

    public static MyNumericClass<T> operator *(MyNumericClass<T> left, double right)
    {
        return right * left;
    }

    //Does not resolve ambiguity and neither does a base class or interface
    public static double operator *(MyNumericClass<T> left, dynamic right)
    {
        return right * left;
    }

    //OK but work only for same type operands
    public static double operator *(MyNumericClass<T> left, MyNumericClass<T> right)
    {
        return left.Value * right.Value;
    }

    ////****Pseudo Code for different type operands - not OK****
    //public static double operator *<TRight>(MyNumericClass<T> left, MyNumericClass<TRight> right)
    //{
    //    return left.Value * right.Value;
    //}

    static void Test()
    {
        MyNumericClass<int> i = new MyNumericClass<int>();
        MyNumericClass<int> j = new MyNumericClass<int>();
        MyNumericClass<string> s = new MyNumericClass<string>();
        double r1 = i * j;
        double r2 = i * s; //The call is ambiguous...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, Why are you using generic class in first place? You're not even using `T` type parameter. What's the point in having the class generic then?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The code is only a small fraction of my class for demonstration purposes. The generic is very much needed in my project.

Comment: If you have an implicit conversion to `double` you don't need specific overloads for multiplication. In `double r2 = i * s;` both `i` and `s` will implicitly be converted into `double` and then the usual `double` multiplication will be performed.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you want to use it in the future.
You can either:

Make a non-generic base class which contains Value. The operator then works on the base class.

Implement an interface and use covariance.

Like this:

```
void Main()
{
    MyNumericClass<int> i = new MyNumericClass<int>();
    MyNumericClass<int> j = new MyNumericClass<int>();
    MyNumericClass<string> s = new MyNumericClass<string>();

    double r1 = i * j;
    double r2 = i * s; 
}

public interface IMyNumericClass<out T> {
    double Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyNumericClass<T> : IMyNumericClass<T>
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public static double operator *(MyNumericClass<T> left, MyNumericClass<T> right)
    {
        return left.Value * right.Value;
    }

    public static double operator *(MyNumericClass<T> left, IMyNumericClass<object> right)
    {
        return left.Value * right.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your interface doesn't needs to be generic, because you're not using `T` type parameter at all. In fact `MyNumericClass<T>` doesn't needs to be generic if this is the original code of OP.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I would assume he posted an example snippet of code; while his main implementation does infact use generics. He asked for a solution to overloading operators using generics. For me to provide an answer with a non-generic solution doesn't answer his question at all.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *For me to provide an answer with a non-generic solution doesn't answer his question at all?* Even though your interface is generic, it doesn't needs to be generic(because you're not using `T` parameter). So it perfectly makes sense to have a non generic interface.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel See my answer to your comment in my original question.

Comment: @Rod This falls into the same category as a non-generic base class. It will not resolve ambiguous calls (see my comment on Sriram Sakthivel's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do it like this

```
public class MyNumericClass<T>
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    //OK but works only for same type operands
    public static double operator *(MyNumericClass<T> left, MyNumericClass<double> right)
    {

        return left.Value * right.Value;
    }
    public static double operator *(MyNumericClass<T> left, MyNumericClass<T> right)
    {

        return left.Value * right.Value;
    }

    static void Test()
    {
        MyNumericClass<int> i = new MyNumericClass<int>();
        MyNumericClass<int> i2 = new MyNumericClass<int>();
        MyNumericClass<double> j = new MyNumericClass<double>();
        double r1 = i * i2;
        double r2 = i * j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very specific and not practical for a lot of different possibilities like `<double>`, `<string>` etc...