# How to overload operators on a generic class if its generic type has those operators?

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

Let's say I have a generic matrix type:

```cs
class Matrix<T>
{
    private T[,] _data;
}
```

Is it possible to overload the `+` operator on `Matrix<T>` *if and only if* `T` has an overloaded `+` operator?

Having written a lot of Rust lately, I was hoping this would work:

```
class Matrix<T>
{
    private T[,] _data;

    public static Matrix<T> operator+(Matrix<T> lhs, Matrix<T> rhs)
        where T: IAdditionOperators<T>
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Sadly, `where` can only be applied to generic parameters of the method itself, not of its containing class.

I know I can drop the `where` clause and use `dynamic` in the method body to perform the addition, but the [performance implications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881741/14637) are not acceptable in my case.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756954/arithmetic-operator-overloading-for-a-generic-class-in-c-sharp) is similar but would be solved with the new `IAdditionOperator<T>` interface in C# 11. However, I want my `Matrix<T>` type to work with types `T` that don't have an addition operator too. (It's okay if this is checked at runtime though.)

Maybe something with a subclass and implicit conversions?

Comment: In this particular example, wonder why not just do `class Matrix<T> where T: IAdditionOperators<T, T, T>` ? I.e. add a constraint on a class level. Because it's hard to imagine for me that Matrix<T> would be practical if T is not IAdditionOperators, and even if there is such necessity may be to have it a separate matrix class

Comment: `Matrix` is just an example; my actual class is also used with `enum`s for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible as far as I know.

The simplest workaround would be extension methods:

```
static class MatrixExt{
    public static Matrix<T> Add(this Matrix<T> a, Matrix<T> b) where T: IAdditionOperators<T>{
          ...
     }
}
```

This would require that the actual data is public accessible somehow.

There have been talks about "extension operators", but nothing that has been added to the language.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I guess I'll have to live with this somewhat more clunky syntax.