# Generics that restricts the types to Int, Double, long

Tags: c#

Is it possible to constraint a method so that it receives only `int`, `double`, `long` or other numerical types that has the usual numerical operations ( such as `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`) defined?

Comment: You could probably create an interface with those operations, and wrap the numerical data types in something that implements that interface.  It probably wont be the most efficient, and will use a bunch of custom stuff, but it will solve that problem if that is the most important thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74796391/199364: *C# 11 / .NET 7 gives us this: "... where T : INumber<T>" ...*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not possible currently.

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694/creating-a-math-library-using-generics-in-c) for a possible workaround

Comment: The fact that there's no common base type for the numeric types is really unfortunate.

Comment: I would prefer the ability to specify operator type constraints

Comment: Too bad; that should be the No 1 thing .Net 4.0 ought to fix

Comment: +1 to @rpetrich Operator constraints would be freaking awesome.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 18):

No, unfortunately there is no such restriction possible. The closest you can get is using `struct, IConvertible` as generic type constraint.

You may want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756954/arithmetic-operator-overloading-for-a-generic-class-in-c) though.

Comment: I am surprised as to why this from Lucero was not voted. Using structs is the closest one can restrict the type parameter to be of value types