# Limit a generic type argument only to be a numeric type

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance, types

I am making a class, `class numToBin <T>`, and I need to make sure that `T` is a numeric value (Ex., `Float, Double, Int, Long, UInt, Ulong, byte, short, BigInteger`).  I have seen a lot of posts asking the same question, but they are all a couple of years old.

My question is:  Have there been any changes to the language to allow it now?
 Currently I have:

```
class numToBin <T>
    where T : struct, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable, IComparable, IComparable<T>
```

But something like `T a = 0;` doesn't work.

Comment: "has there been any changes to the language to allow it now?" No.

Comment: Could you link an answer or two that you think is out of date?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267902/generics-where-t-is-a-number https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329576/generic-constraint-to-match-numeric-types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645301/generics-that-restricts-the-types-to-int-double-long    Just some examples...

Comment: I updated the title of your question to more clearly describe what you were trying to do.  I fixed the formatting, a few minor grammar and punctuation errors, and corrected your capitalization.  I also turned the snippet of your existing code into a cleaner, neatly-indented, more-readable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is still no generic type constraint for a "numeric" type.

To get your `T a = 0` specifically you can just use `T a = default(T)`. The default of all numeric types is 0.

Comment: Ok, then how would one do a += 2 for example?

Comment: @OptimisticPeach You can't. There is no numeric interface or constraint.

Comment: To check for each of the types could I just do `if(default(T) == 0)`?

Comment: @OptimisticPeach I'm guessing not, the compiler will think you are comparing an object to an int (checked in interactive window).

Comment: @BradlryDotNet Ok, thanks. I will implement a method to check if it is numeric

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your class, perform type inspection to match the applicable types.  If it fails throw an InvalidCastException or InvalidArgumentException.

```
Type t = typeof(T);
bool good = (t == typeof(int)) || (t == typeof(long))|| //...
if(!good)
 //die
```

Comment: Ok, but if i do `Type[] types = { typeof(double) ....}` then, `(types[2]) a` doesn't really work, neither does `a+=1`

Comment: The list of numeric primitives isn't very long, just check all of them.