# Generic method where T is type1 or type2

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-construction

Is there a way to declare a generic function that the generic type is of type1 **or** type2?

example:

```
public void Foo<T>(T number)
{
}
```

Can I constraint T to be int or long

Comment: [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: @BoltClock, Because my code breaks when the parameter isn't one of the primitive(int, long, double...) and I want to get errors on compilation not on RunTime

Comment: Related: [Generic method multiple(OR) type constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10833918)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Although you could use a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to limit the type of each generic argument T, unfortunately there is none that would allow you to enforce at compile time whether T is `type1 or type2`.

Nor is there any way to enforce at compile time that your generic argument can only be of any primitive type (int, long, double, ...).

Answer (score 26):

For ReferenceType objects you can do

```
public void DoIt<T>(T someParameter) where T : IMyType
{

}
```

...

```
public interface IMyType
{
}

public class Type1 : IMyType
{
}

public class Type2 : IMyType
{
}
```

For your case using long as parameter will constrain usage to longs and ints anyway.

```
public void DoIt(long someParameter)
{

}
```

to constrain to any value types (like: int, double, short, decimal) you can use:

```
public void DoIt<T>(T someParameter) where T : struct
{

}
```

for more information you can check official documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: Does this work only with interface? Would base class be allowed?

Comment: @liang Yes you could use a Base Class or a Base Abstract Class or Interface.

Answer (score 9):

No.

That doesn't make sense; `T` would not have any usable compile-time type in the method.

Instead, you should make two overloaded methods.

Comment: I think it does make sense. I have a code that if you pass a parameter different then double, decimal, float, int, long etc' will brake. I want to verify this at compilation. Doesn't make sense?

Comment: @gdoron: From your point of view, it makes sense.  From the compiler's point of view, it does not make sense, since `T` would not be a usable type.

Comment: In this case the compiler can treat `T` as the common of type1 and type2, where there is no relation `T` is `object`...

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question, if you read between the lines. It seems he is asking for a constraint such as `where T : number` which unfortunately doesn't exist. Still, it would be a construct that makes sense...

Answer (score 5):

Use overloaded methods instead:

```
public void Foo(int number)
{
} 

public void Foo(long number)
{
}
```

You cannot perform arithmetical operations on generic types anyway. Note that you can pass an `int` value to a `long` parameter. It will automatically be converted to `long`. Having just a single method with a `long` parameter could therefore be sufficient.

Older programming languages worked after the principle "There can be only one". C# allows you to have several methods with the same name in the same class, interface or struct. These methods must have a different signature. This means, that they must have a different number of parameters or parameters with different types (or both). This is called method overloading.

Comment: I can't write 20 method for each numeric value type. this is what Generics **should have** solved

Comment: Artihmetic operations are not supported on generic type parameters. See `System.Text.StringBuilder` for an example. It defines more than 20 `Append()` overloads for differents types.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, and this doesn't perfectly answer it, but you can do this with a single method, rather than creating multiples, or using generic constraints... especially useful if you have 20 odd types to check.

Obviously you don't get the compiler type checking as you do when using a constraint, but this can help in certain circumstances...

```
public void MyMethod<T>()
{
    if (!typeof(T).Equals(typeof(int)) &&
        !typeof(T).Equals(typeof(long)))
            throw new Exception("T must be int or long");

    //your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694/creating-a-math-library-using-generics-in-c-sharp) about creating a math library sort of covers the same ground, and includes some work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I think I found a better solution (assuming an overloaded version of your method is insufficient):

Mixing `Type1` and `Type2` without any parallels does not make any sense as has been written already. So there has to be any method or property accessed for both object types. To make sure for the compiler that these methods or properties are available for your object, group `Type1` and `Type2` by creating an interface `MyInterface` and implementing it by `Type1` and `Type2`:

```
interface MyInterface {
  void MyCommonMethod();
  bool MyCommonProperty { get; }
}

class Type1 : MyInterface {
  void MyCommonMethod() {
    // TODO: Implement it for Type1
  }

  bool MyCommonProperty {
  get {
    // TODO: Implement it for Type1
  }
  }
}

class Type2 : MyInterface {
  void MyCommonMethod() {
    // TODO: Implement it for Type2
  }

  bool MyCommonProperty {
  get {
    // TODO: Implement it for Type2
  }
  }
}
```

Now, to rewrite your `Foo` method to accept both `Type1` and `Type2`, constraint `T` to be an `MyInterface` object:

```
public void Foo<T>(T number) where T : MyInterface
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I mope this might be helpful. :)